# Gradle can't find dependency (Android support library)

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

I have a problem that Gradle can't find my dependency (Android support library).

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/FlurryAgent.jar')
    compile group: 'com.google.android', name: 'support-v4', version: 'r7'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

When I build (on commandline, no IDE) I get the following message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'AndroidCalculator'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
      > Could not find com.google.android:support-v4:r7.
        Required by:
            :AndroidCalculator:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Why am I not allowed to add the Android Support library like this?

Comment: how about workaround this problem by set dependency based on file path like this?

     compile files("path_to_your_sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar",

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have declared a *repository dependency*, but haven't declared a *repository*. Hence the dependency cannot be resolved. (Repositories/dependencies in the `buildscript` block are strictly separated from repositories/dependencies in the main build script.)

Comment: Specifically, add this as a root item to your build.gradle: repositories {
    mavenCentral()
} 

Details: http://www.jayway.com/2013/02/26/using-gradle-for-building-android-applications/

Answer (score 8):

http://pastebin.com/FmcCZwA5

This paste is elaborate project with AndroidAnnotations, Dagger, Jackson and Robolectric.

all you need is add

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

replace

```
 compile group: 'com.google.android', name: 'support-v4', version: 'r7'
```

with (line 44 of the code linked above)

```
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
```

**Gotchas**: Last bit will works on Android Studio 0.2+ only if you had a fresh install. Since 0.2 Studio is shipped with its internal m2 repo to provide support and google api libraries so if you upgraded from previous versions your SDK doesn't have it.

also make sure local.properties file is present in root folder and sdk.dir points to SDK

Answer (score 2):

You need to add additional `dependency` in `dependencies` tag. If you have `android-support-v4.jar` library in your `libs` folder, try to add code listed below:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

Comment: I don't think one needs to put this jar into their libs folder explicitly.  That was the old way of doing things in Eclipse.  Instead, Gradle and Android studio will now fetch the latest support library and package it in your project automatically if you add the 'compile' dependency.

Comment: You sir, are the real MVP