# Gradle can't find library

Tags: android, gradle, otto

I am trying to include Otto library in my project, but am getting this error:

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':maptest:_debugCompile'.
> Could not find com.squareup:otto:1.3.4.
```

I have tried cleaning project, running **Tools -> android -> sync** project with gradle files but that gives me the same error.

My build.gradle is the following:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    }
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
}
```

Comment: Check this link .. here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539888/gradle-could-not-resolve-otto-library?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add maven central repository, so gradle know where so search for library.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: That is there, should it be also in another place?

Comment: Yes it should also as root element. You only have it inside `buildscript`, add it once more outside `buildscript`

Answer (score 1):

Did you import Otto library into `Android Private Libraries`? Try clean project this way: **Project -> Clean...**

You may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673579/gradle-cant-find-dependency-android-support-library) out.